# jQuery Remove <br> from <ul>, <ol>

Tags: jquery

I have a code generated by PHP which has unwanted br tags.
How can I remove the `<br>` when appears immediately after opening `<ul>` ie: it is not inside `<li>`
How can I remove `<br>` when it is immediately after closing tag of `</ul>`

```
<ul>
    <br>
    <li> ....</li>
    <li> ....</li>
    <li> ....</li>
</ul>
<br>
```

Comment: If you can correct it in PHP itself, that would be best.

Comment: unfortunately it is done through complex REGEX and ...

Comment: I think this is one of the rare cases where you can solve the problem with a regular expression instead of jQuery.

Comment: @Hanno no, no, no, no, NO!

Answer (score 6):

Seeing as the *only* legal child of a `<ul>` is an `<li>` tag:

```
$('ul').children(':not(li)').remove();
```

or if you want to be more specific and only address this specific error:

```
$('ul > br').remove();
```

To remove a `<br>` that *follows* a `<ul>`, you can use the "preceding" CSS selector:

```
$('ul + br').remove();
```

Note that the latter does *not* refer just to the "opening" `<ul>` tag, but the entire `<ul>` *element* up to and including its closing `</ul>` tag.

Answer (score 4):

To remove the `<br />` after the `<ul>` is closed you can use this:

```
$("ul").next("br").remove();
```

To remove the `<br />` inside the `<ul>`, you can use this:

```
$('ul').children(':not(li)').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Precisely from your reqirements

```
$('ul').next('br').remove();
$('ul').first('br').remove();
```

But, [Alnitak](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16716273/1912431) has a more elegant way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use JS only, use CSS `display : none`.

If someone desactive JS, the br will still be there. Do this instead :

```
ul > br{display : none};
```

If you want to remove it for a better source code, use this :

```
$('ul > br').remove()
```

If you want to delete the br next to te ul, use thos selector instead :

CSS

```
ul + br
```

jQuery

```
$('ul + br')
```

Comment: if you don't have CSS3 support, jQuery can do stuff with its Sizzle engine that CSS can't, so it might be a good idea to do both.

Comment: Yes but those are CSS 2 selector anyway. And it is actually always better to have both.

Comment: ah yes, `E + F` is indeed CSS2

Answer (score -1):

here is a demo for your questiov

```
jQuery("ul").siblings("br").each(function(){
jQuery(this).remove();});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/animesh/hx48k/1/)